# How do I compile QTWrapper lib with the given lib at once?

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, libusb

I have been looking for Qt USB solution and came across [this QtUSB wrapper](https://github.com/fpoussin/QtUsb), which looks the most promising. It wraps around [libusb 1.0](http://libusb.info/) And upon examining the source code in the `/src` directory, I see a reference to

```
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
```

I have not compiled libusb not I have it installed using apt-get on my Ubuntu machine. I would like to have a solution, where all source files are included in my master solution and I compile this at once on all platforms I need.

I.E. I do not wish to compile the 3 modules separately and link to each other, rather I'd like to include them into my solution and build all at once.

How should I proceed? Whatever I try is giving me some errors with some components not present or some classes not defined. I placed all QtUSB files into /QUSB directory in my project and I imported all files into Qt Creator. I then did the same for /QUSB/libusb-1.0 files.

Comment: Did you manage to compile libusb? If so, compile it as a static library and distribute it as is in your installation. You could keep the source code in your project, but you don't need to compile it every time.